# If $p\mid 2^n\pm1$ with $p$ and $n$ relatively prime, then $p$ is a Wieferich prime iff $p^2$ also divides $2^n\pm 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The Wolfram Mathworld article on Wieferich primes states:

> $2^{p-1}-1\equiv 0 \mod p.$ If the first case of Fermat's last theorem is false for exponent $p$,
>   then $p$ must be a Wieferich prime (Wieferich 1909). **If $p\mid 2^n\pm1$ with
>   $p$ and $n$ relatively prime, then $p$ is a Wieferich prime iff $p^2$
>   also divides $2^n\pm 1$.**

Is there a short proof for this (bolded) statement or should we scan through the reference papers listed at the bottom of the mentioned article?

Comment: Just edited the question. Looking for a proof of the last sentence.

Comment: Perhaps, the definition of Wieferich-primes helps. A prime $p$ is a Wieferich-prime if and only if $p^2$ divides $2^{p-1}-1$.